# Database table size and mysql query execution time

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table which has about 500000 rows. When I use mysql select query the execution time is quite long, about 0.4 seconds. Same query from a smaller table takes about 0.0004 seconds.

Is there any solutions to make this query faster?

Comment: Please provide the query, the table strcuture, and the indexes the table has.

Answer (score 3):

0. Most important thing: [Use an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), suitable for your where-clause.
   0.1) Use an index, that covers not only the where clause, but also all selected columns. This way the result can be returned by only using the index and not loading the data from the actual rows indentifed by the index.
1. If that is not enough you can even use an index that contains all rows that need to be returned by your query. So the query can look up everything from the index and does not have to load the actual rows.
2. Reduce the number of returned columns to the columns you really need. Don't select all columns if you are not using every one of them.
3. Use data types appropriate to the stored data, and choose the smalles data types possible. E.g. when you have to store a number that will never exceed 100 you can use a `TINYINT` that only consumes 1 byte instead of a `BIGINT` that will use 8 byte in every row ([integer types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so so much!

Comment: @MarianneSjöberg: Would you like to accept my answer?